# How to display div inside another div like table with some row and column dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a general DIV that contains any dynamic DIV.

For Example I have a general div(container) with width size 100%, the general div contains 10 child div's inside it, I need to seperate the 10 child div as two row inside the general div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Note: First 5 div's should be in one row and Next 5 div's should be in another row.
It is possibile to do this dynamically?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: div {overflow: hidden;}
div div {float: left;}

Comment: can you be more clear...Can you put up the expected output

Comment: @Jonas Grumann, thaks your code works

Answer (score 0):

you can change the display in css like this:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

.myClass {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and the html like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="myClass">1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div class="myClass">222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</div>
  <div class="myClass">333333333333333333333333333333333333333</div>
  <div class="myClass">444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444</div>
  <div class="myClass">55555555555555555555555555555555555555</div>
  <div class="myClass">66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666</div>
  <div class="myClass">7777777777777777777777777777777777777777</div>
  <div class="myClass">88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888</div>
  <div class="myClass">99999999999999999999999999999999999</div>
  <div class="myClass">1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the divs to display in rows and wrap like table cells. Something like this.

CSS:

```
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: white;
}
div.container div {
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px 1px 0 0;
}
div.container.three-per-row div {
  width: calc(100%/3 - 2px);
}
div.container.four-per-row div {
  width: calc(100%/4 - 2px);
}
```

This is compiled. [JSBIN link is SCSS](https://jsbin.com/guqesowoto/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float css property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Example of making a grid using css: 
https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/